# Google Cloud Platform - receiving a 502 error for a backend not passing health checks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, http-status-code-504, pega

I have been following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-pega-platform-using-compute-engine-and-cloud-sql) to deploy Pega 7.4 on Google Cloud compute engine. Everything went smoothly however on the Load Balancer health check the service continues to be unhealthy.

[image]

When visiting the external IP a 502 is returned and in trying to troubleshoot GCP told us to "Make sure that your backend is healthy and supports HTTP/2 protocol". Well in the guide this command:

```
gcloud compute backend-services create pega-app \
    --health-checks=pega-health \
    --port-name=pega-web \
    --session-affinity=GENERATED_COOKIE \
    --protocol=HTTP --global
```

The protocol is HTTP but is this the same as HTTP/2?

What else could be wrong besides checking that the firewall setup allows the health checker and load balancer to pass through (below)?

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create pega-internal \
    --description="Pega node to node communication requirements" \
    --action=ALLOW \
    --rules=tcp:9300-9399,tcp:5701-5800 \
    --source-tags=pega-app \
    --target-tags=pega-app
gcloud compute firewall-rules create pega-web-external \
    --description="Pega external web ports" \
    --action=ALLOW \
    --rules=tcp:8080,tcp:8443 \
    --source-ranges=130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16 \
    --target-tags=pega-app
```

Edit:
So the Instance group has a named port on 8080

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-named-ports pega-app \
    --named-ports=pega-web:8080 \
    --region=${REGION}
```

And the health check config:

```
gcloud compute health-checks create http pega-health \
    --request-path=/prweb/PRRestService/monitor/pingservice/ping \
    --port=8080
```

I have checked VM Instance logs on the pega-app and getting 404 when trying to hit the ping service. 
[image]

Comment: HTTP/2 is an enhancement to the HTTP protocol. However, almost nobody supports HTTP/2 over HTTP. HTTP/2 is usually over HTTPS. I don't know why Google Support told you HTTP/2. If your healthcheck is HTTP that is all that is needed.

Comment: Add to your question how you have the healthcheck configured.

Comment: When I have problems with backend instance healthcheck problems, and the obvious does not solve it, I launch a new instance and then use curl to check that the healthcheck endpoint responds.

Comment: You know that HTTP goes on the port 80 right? Because when reading your firewall-rules I don't see it...

Comment: @night-gold Yes I have frontend forwading rule:
`gcloud compute forwarding-rules create pega-app \
    --global \
    --address=$(gcloud compute addresses describe pega-app --global --format 'value(address)') \
    --ip-protocol=TCP \
    --ports=80 \
    --target-http-proxy=pega-app`

Comment: That's still not a firewall rules on port 80 :D

Comment: Since load balancer health check the service continues to be unhealthy,therefore verify and make sure:

 1) Service is running on the port configured.
 2) Service is not bind to any specific IP rather bind to all IP addresses i.e 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Can you confirm that the issue is solved and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I used a configured using a Static IP address without applying a domain name system record like this: gcloud compute addresses create pega-app --global I skipped this step so it generates ephemeral IP addresses each time the instances have to boot up.